# How to BLAST against TrEMBL only

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, blast, ncbi, protein-database

I am doing command-line BLAST with BioPython. I need to search against TrEMBL, but I have not been able to find how to do that. I know I can select db="nr", and that works, but I want to search only against TrEMBL, which constitues a subset of nr sequences. Also, I need to be able to do that on-line, not remotely!

EDIT: If anyone ever encounters the same problem: After much experimentation, the only way that I managed to make this work was to download NCBI BLAST+ and do a remote search on a stand-alone prepared library. Get in touch with me if in doubt.

Comment: As far as I know BioPython uses the NCBI BLAST and NCBI does not have a index for TrEMBL, only for SwissProt.

Comment: It looks like it is indexed: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/sss/ncbiblast/

Comment: BioPython works against the NCBI page while EBI uses NCBI's BLAST program but a different database.